# Can I assume composition?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a set with an equivalence relation $\sim$. Let $f : X/\sim \ \to Y$ be a function. We deﬁne a function $\tilde{f}$, called the lift of $f$, as follows: $\tilde{f} : X \to Y$, $x \mapsto f([x])$.

(a) If $f$ is injective, then $\tilde{f}$ is injective. Prove or give a counterexample.

(b) If $f$ is surjective, then $\tilde{f}$ is surjective. Proof or give a counterexample.

My question here is, can I just assume that $\tilde{f} = f \circ \pi$, where $\pi: X \to X/ \sim$ is the quotient map? For (b), since $\pi$ is surjective and we assume $f$ is surjective, then $\tilde{f}$ is surjective. For (a), to show a counter example, I have to pick a specific $X,Y$, and function $f$ such that $\tilde{f}$ is not injective? So this:

Let $X = \mathbb{Z}$ and let $Y=\{0,1\}$. Define the relation $\sim$ by $a \sim b \iff a \equiv b \mod 2$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. The equivalence classes are $[0]$ and $[1]$, so $X / \sim \ = \{[0], [1]\}$. Now define $f: X/ \sim \ \to Y$ by $[0] \mapsto 0$ and $[1] \mapsto 1$, and let $\tilde{f}$ be defined as above. Note that $f$ is clearly injective. Consider $1,3 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Of course, $1\ne 3$, but since $3 \equiv 1 \mod 2$, we see that $[1]=[3]$. So 
$$
\tilde{f}(1) = f([1])=f([3])= \tilde{f}(3).
$$ 
Thus, $\tilde{f}$ is not injective even though $f$ is injective.

Also, what is a lift exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assume that $$\overline{f} = f\circ \pi$$ since $(f\circ \pi)(x) = f(\pi(x)) = f([x]) = \overline{f}(x)$.

a) This is not true in general. We can prove it by contraposition. Assume $\overline{f}$ is not injective and $\sim$ is given by $x\sim x' :\Leftrightarrow \overline{f}(x) = \overline{f}(x')$. That is, we identify all elements of $X$ that have a common image in $Y$.

But even though $\overline{f}$ was not injective, $f$ is injective since $[x] \not= [x']$ now implies $f([x]) \not= f([x'])$.

b) Your thoughts on b) are correct.

In category theory a *lift* describes the following:

given a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ and a morphism $g\colon Z \to Y$, a *lift*  of $f$ to $Z$ is a morphism $h\colon X \to Z$ such that $$f = g\circ h.$$ That is, $f$ factors through $h$.

If you are not familiar with category theory, the morphisms in the category of topological spaces are the continous maps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very helpful. I see that you can prove it is not true through contraposition, but I believe the question wants me to show it via counter example. Is what I asked a valid way to go about finding a counter example?

Comment: Take $ X = \{a,b,c\}, Y = \{1,2\}$ and $\overline{f}:X\to Y$ such that $a\mapsto 1, b\mapsto 1, c\mapsto 2$. This is clearly not injective. Now let $a\sim b :\Leftrightarrow f(a) = f(b)$ be the equivalence relation. We have $X/\sim = \{[a],[c]\}$. Thus $f:(X/\sim)\to Y$ is injective since $[a] \mapsto 1, [c]\mapsto 2$ but that certainly does not imply that $\overline{f}$ is injective.

Note that this is just one explicit example of the general claim we've proven for a).

Comment: Here you defined $\tilde{f}$. Isn't it already defined? Don't we have to define $f$ first and then $\tilde{f}$ is induced from that?

Comment: Ok, so maybe this will clear it up. Does the example I just added in my revised initial post work?

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: So what's the difference between yours and mine besides the examples? I defined $f$ and then got the definition for $\tilde{f}$ from the prompt. You defined $\tilde{f}$ explicitly first.

Comment: I just noticed your approach is correct, mine wasn't. $f$ is given and induces $\overline{f}$. I did a mistake above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, ok. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad i could help.